# canActivate issue with durandal 2.0.1

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I downloaded Durandal 2.0.1 StarterKit and I am using it for a web project. I worked with it for a while now.

In one of my viewmodels I am using the routing with id in the url: `route: 'test/:id'`. Since I want to protect against random id inputs from the user, I am using the `canAvtivate` function, in which I perform some checks.

When I'm trying to access the route from another route the `canActivate` function is evaluated before activating, but when i just change the id value in the url the function is not called. It happens the same if I say `router.navigate("#/test/44");` from within that view.

Is this desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess as I haven't played much with parameterized routing yet, but perhaps the active module is being reused?   Does the section "Module Reuse" at the link below apply in your situation?

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/

Perhaps you can work around this by implementing `canReuseForRoute`

Comment: By implementing `canReuseForRoute` I managed to get the `canActivate` evaluate.